# How Can I Find Good Resources to Learn About the $SU(5)$ and $SO(10)$ Grand Unified Theories Without an Extensive Background in the Field?

Tags: resource-recommendations, group-theory, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

I'm a first-year university student. My group and I have been tasked with finding out whether, given current scientific consensus, it looks like a viable Grand Unified Theory (GUT) can be found. We have been tasked to make a video, detailing our findings, targeted towards our peers. I am a part of the research team and we have decided to research the *SU*(5) and *SO*(10) theories as candidates for a GUT. I've been struggling somewhat to get through the complicated mathematical explanations of lie groups, gauge couplings and other technical concepts that I don't believe we have the time to fully research and comprehend.

I come here, asking the Physics Stack Exchange community for guidance on finding resources such as [this one](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2021/01/26/the-dream-of-string-theory-is-an-unlikely-broken-box/?sh=7ec8a7d73b3f), which lay out a view of a scientific theory (String Theory as a Theory of Everything, in this case) in a way more friendly to non-experts. I understand that these sorts of resources are somewhat rudimentary for learning in that they cut out a lot of the important nuance present in more expert-targeted, robust, complicated texts or reviews. However, given the time constraint and our task, an extremely deep and nuanced understanding of GUTs seems like neither a realistic expectation nor an important one. What advice would you have that would help my team and I gain an understanding of the current scientific consensus on GUTs, such as the *SU*(5) and *SO*(10) theories, given our lack of expertise in the field?

Comment: You are a first year university student and you are going to look at $SU(5)$ and $SO(10)$ as GUT candidates? Hilarious! What’s on your list for next week? Maybe a Millennium Problem.

Comment: Never say never, but this seems impossible. Is that really your task?

Comment: @Javier, our task is simpler than I may have explained. I believe the workaround to the obvious interpretation of the task as "find a GUT" is to look at it as more of a "determine whether scientists seem confident that we can find a GUT". Our task is more to observe and collect data from both sides of the argument and synthesise that information into an argument, if possible. Then, if not that's possible, or if scientific consensus is unclear on both sides, we'd focus on that and describe what is currently known and the unclear nature of that knowledge.

Comment: These theories have been around for over 40 years. What is your guess as to what happened?

Comment: @ChristianAlbina you have edited the question to tone it down substantially. I suggest you check out the archives of Scientific American and similar magazines. But I can assure you that very few physicist learn their stuff from reading Forbes.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176924/2451