# Resource Recommendation for Grand Unified Theory

Tags: resource-recommendations, group-theory, grand-unification

Recently I have started studying grand unified theories. One department where I found myself lacking in group theory. Can anybody tell to what level group theory is needed to understand Grand unified theories? For example, is the knowledge of exceptional compact groups necessary?
Also, on another note for grand unified theories, I am following R.N. Mohapatra's 'Unification and Supersymmetry The Frontiers of Quark Lepton Physics.' Can anybody recommend another source for it? I usually like to follow more than one source.

Comment: In addition to whatever people suggest, I recommend reading the original paper by Georgi and Glashow!

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176924/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6108/2451 and links therein.